# How to optimize the code? (reverse string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

The task says : Change the order of words in a sentence but let non-alphanumerical characters stay in the same place e.g: 'Hello, it is world here.' -> "here, world is it Hello."

So far i have created something like this, but i need to optimize it (there are too many loops).

```js
var text = 'Hello, it is world here.';

function reverseFunc(text){
  let alpha = text.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi).reverse();
  let nonAlpha = text.match(/[\W_]+/gi);
  let result = [];
  console.log("Alpha : " + alpha)
  console.log("Non alpha : " +nonAlpha)

 if(alpha == null || nonAlpha == null) console.log(text)
 else if((/[a-z0-9]/i).test(text.split("")[0])){
   if (alpha.length == nonAlpha.length) {
     for (let i = 0; i < nonAlpha.length; i++) {
      result.push(alpha[i], nonAlpha[i]);
     }
     console.log(result.join(""))
     return(result.join(""))
   }else{
     for (let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
      result.push(alpha[i], nonAlpha[i]);
    }
     console.log(result.join(""))
     return(result.join(""))
   }
 }else{
   if (nonAlpha.length == alpha.length) {
     for (let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
      result.push(nonAlpha[i], alpha[i]);
     }
     console.log(result.join("")) 
     return(result.join(""))
   }else{
     for (let i = 0; i < nonAlpha.length; i++) {
      result.push(nonAlpha[i], alpha[i]);
    }
     console.log(result.join(""))
     return(result.join(""))
   }
 }
}
reverseFunc(text)
```

I also have a problem when the text is only 1 char long  e.g ".", or " ". I tried this:

```
if(alpha == null || nonAlpha == null) console.log(text)
```

but it seems like it is working only for alphanumeric chars.How could this algorithm be corrected?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qyjuvf2L/

Comment: @mplungjan: nice attempt, but it assumes that the sentence starts with a word. Which may not necessarily be the case (for example, spanish question marks, "¿Cómo te llamas?")

Comment: Haven't read your code too closely but it seems to be overly complicated for this problem. You could leverage the existing "replace substring by regex" functionality. For example, 1) collect all words in a string. 2) replace all words with a marker string, 3) replace all marker strings with previously collected words, starting from the last word. An example implementation in ruby: https://onlinegdb.com/nMTS86sny

Comment: On a second thought, no need to bother with a placeholder: https://onlinegdb.com/ay--IOphk

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Without any other information, until otherwise informed, we can assume that it is a standard English sentence without hyphens and other weirdness.

Comment: Ah yes, hyphens. Always forget about them. They are "standard english", though :) But I get what you mean.